# Ham Sandwich theorem used in combinatorics problem involving beads on a necklace

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Ok, so according to a friend of mine you can use the ham sandwich to prove the following theorem: Suppose there is a necklace with $m$ types of beads and $2n_1,2n_2...2n_m$ beads of each colors. So $2n_i$ beads of the type $i$.

According to him using ham sandwich we can prove we can always make $m+1$ cuts to divide the necklace into $m$ strings so that we can then put these strings in two piles so each pile has half of each type of bead.

Comment: It has something to do with making a random cut and placing the string in R^n on top of the curve $r,r^2...r^n$ and seeing any hyperplane cuts it at at most n points.

Comment: A wild guess: Lefschetz hyperplane theorem? BTW: do you mean that $m=2n_1+2n_2+....2n_m$, or you have $m+2n_1+2n_2+...+2n_m$ beads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how it works now. The idea is to cut the necklace once so that it becomes a string. You then place the string on the moments curve of degree $m$ and give each type of bead a measure in $\mathbb R^m$ so that the measure is zero outside of the bead and uniform insde the beads of that type. You then apply the Ham Sandwich theorem. and get a hyperplane that cuts $\mathbb R^m$ into two semiplanes with equal measure for all the measures. The hyperplane then leaves the same amount of beads in every half because points on the moment curve are in general position. Moreover there are at most $n$ intersection points of the semiplane and the moment curve. Using this we mark where we have to make the cuts and then take the string back to our world, where we proceed to make the cuts.